# How to delete/clear AppData/Roaming/MyFolder files during uninstall using qt installer framework?

Tags: qt, installation, qt-installer

I create a application using qt installer framework. Now uninstalling my app does not remove AppData/Roaming/My app folder. So i tried my custom code for uninstall to clear my AppData. But this makes my installer unresponsive.

```
Controller.prototype.FinishedPageCallback = function() {

if (installer.isUninstaller() && installer.status == QInstaller.Success)  
     {    
            var appDataPath = QDesktopServices.storageLocation(QDesktopServices.AppDataLocation) + "\\My app";



         if(installer.fileExists(appDataPath) === true)    
         {
                installer.executeDetached("cmd",["/c", "rd", "/q", "/s", appDataPath]);
         }

            gui.clickButton(buttons.FinishButton);
    }  
}
```

I also tried using

```
if(installer.runUninstall === true)    

     { 
         installer.performOperation("Execute" , "cmd" "C:/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Roaming/My App", "rd", "/s", "/q");  
     }
```

Does not work either. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does your command work in the command line?

Comment: yes it work in command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing with the installer operations found that Rmdir/ Execute does not work as expected . But delete operation worked for me.

```
installer.performOperation("Delete","@HomeDir@/AppData/Roaming/My App/myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Great! I have tried with component. It doesn't work.

Comment: I'm creating an IFW installer using CMake and need to put my files in %APPDATA% as I'm installing a plug-in into another application. `@HomeDir@` works perfectly! `set(CPACK_IFW_TARGET_DIRECTORY "@HomeDir@/AppData/Roaming/Application/Plugins/MyPlugin")`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the culprit is the space between 'My' and 'App'. Provide quotes **within** the string:

```
"\"C:/Users/%USERNAME%/AppData/Roaming/My App\""
```

Comment: Tried it Does not work, May be there is a different way to clear AppData upon UnInstall ??

Answer (score 0):

There is a good hint in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57077332/2970363). To allow remove the directories created by the installer and updated than it should be `registerPathForUninstallation` method used with parameter `boolean wipe = true`, check more in [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-component.html#registerPathForUninstallation-method).
So the script to create the installer may look as follows:

```
function Component()
{
    // default constructor
    var programFiles = installer.environmentVariable("ProgramFiles");   
    if (programFiles != ""){
         installer.setValue("TargetDir", programFiles + "/My app");
    }
    var appDataRoaming = installer.environmentVariable("AppData");     
    if (appDataRoaming != ""){
        installer.setValue("DataDir", appDataRoaming + "/My app");
    }
    component.registerPathForUninstallation("@DataDir@", true);
}

Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    try {
        // call the base create operations function
        component.createOperations();
        if (installer.value("os") == "win") { 
            try {
                component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/My app.exe", "@StartMenuDir@/My app.lnk", "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@");                
                component.addOperation("Mkdir", "@DataDir@");
            } catch (e) {
                // Do nothing if key doesn't exist
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }     
}
```