# Qt Installer Framework - How to delete only certain files and folers at uninstall

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I use Qt Installer Framework.

How to make sure, at the time of uninstallation, that only certain files or folders are deleted, and not all files in the installation folder as is currently the case?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly override the default behavior of `component.createOperations` for uninstallers then manually specify each path for uninstallation using [`component.registerPathForUninstallation`](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-component.html#registerPathForUninstallation-method).

That might look something like this:

```
function Component() {
    pathsToUninstall = [];
    pathsToUninstall.forEach(function(path) {
        component.registerPathForUninstallation(path);
    });      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (version 3.1.1) the installer removes only those component files that it has installed. If you add something of your own (regardless of the installer), then your files will remain intact.

If you want to manually control this process you can overload
functions [createOperationsForArchive](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-component.html#createOperationsForArchive-method), [createOperationsForPath](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-component.html#createOperationsForPath-method) and [removeComponent](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/qinstaller-component.html#removeComponent) for remove companent